# Drop table but not recreate the table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQl database.
I have a tables that is corrupet. I'm try to do this command from prompt:

```
repair table ordininuovo;
```

but I have the error returned.

So I have `drop table ordininuovo;` and this is OK.

Now I want to re-create this table but if I try to recreate it I have this error:

> ERROR 1050 <42S01>: Table '|cassagestionale'.'ordininuovo' already exists

What is the problem?

Comment: different schema?

Comment: you say the drop table is ok but if then tells you the table still exists then seemingly the drop was not actually successful? Or you dropped a different table, either in a different schema or server maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the TRUNCATE command.  It removed the data but keeps the structure